# How to create IWizard assembly for VS2008 project template

Tags: visual-studio-2008, project-template, formwizard

I have created an IWizard assembly that should take in parameter values (via Windows Form) and insert them where called for by the code contained in a VS 2008 Project template.  Here is the [article I used to set this up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx).

Here's the problem, when I create a new project based on the template, it throws an error stating, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."  I put Message boxes all throughout the RunStarted method in the IWizard class, but none of them show.

[Update]
I attached an instance of VS 2010 to the instance of VS 2008 in which I was created a new project from the template wizard, and saw the following in the output:

*The thread '' (0xc0c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).*

Has anyone got an idea of where I can begin to debug this or what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be, that you rename a filename in the .vstemplate but the entry in your .csproj points to the old filename?

For example in *.vstemplate:

```
 <Folder Name="Logic" TargetFolderName="Logic">
   <ProjectItem ReplaceParameters="true" TargetFileName="$BdName$.cs">BdTemplate.cs</ProjectItem>
 </Folder>
```

You *must* replace the filename in your .csproj, too:

```
<Compile Include="Logic\$BdName$.cs" />
```

Otherwise the project could not be loaded and you get this error.